# 'Admin' content not displaying to users signed in as an admin on my CodeIgniter eCommerce site

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I’m working on an e-Commerce site using the CodeIgniter framework. As such, I want to have part of the website accessible to all visitors, and part accessible only to admins.

I have delegated my login and session functionalities to ‘application/libraries/BaseController.php’ (which is then extended by any controller that needs to use the functionalities).

The problem is that the site does not distinguish between a visitor signed in as a client and a visitor signed in as an admin, so the admin section remains invisible to all.

The isAdmin() function in the base controller checks that the user is an admin by checking that the isAdmin column in the database is equal to 1 (for all other users, this is 0)

```
public function isAdmin(){
    if($this->isAdminBool == 1){ 
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

So far, this works - when I echo the user's name, email, and the value contained in their isAdmin column, all appear as expected.

But then, when I try to use the isAdmin() function to hide a sensitive part of the website (for example, application/controllers/Upload.php), the site doesn't make any distinction between users whose status is 'client' (isAdmin ==0), or 'admin' (isAdmin ==1)

class Upload extends BaseController {

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->isLoggedIn();

}

public function index()
{
    if($this->isAdmin() == TRUE) {  

        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' '));

    } else{


        echo "I'm sorry, you do not have permission to view the secret upload part of the website";


    }
}
```

I've tried many different combinations of

```
if($this->isAdmin() != TRUE)

if($this->isAdmin() != FALSE)
```

etc, but I can't get the controllers that extend the BaseController to distinguish between users signed in as clients, and users signed in as admins. I'm sure there is some very basic error, but I'm really stuck.

I've uploaded the framework and database to https://github.com/Cathalll/Codeigniter-MVC---isAdmin-functoin-not-working

I've created one client

test@test.org | password : 12345678

and one admin

admin1@gite.com  | password: 12345678910

If anyone could give me any advice on this, I would be very grateful - kind of hard to move on with the other parts of the site when they almost all implement this function :/

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts at trying to fix it it, I decided to get rid of the isAdmin() function, and just use:

```
if($this->session->role==='admin') {  

            $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' '));
```

-at the top of each controller where required

Slightly less elegant, but it works ¯_(ツ)_/¯